# IE blocks pdf creation using jQuery with a popup

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, pdf

I have a service that generates custom birthday templates in the form of a pdf.
A user has credits and when he clicks a button, an ajax call is performed to get the number of the created pdf file and then using **window.location** displays the pdf to the user.

Things are fine in chrome and firefox but IE blocks the pdf with a generic bar popup that asks the user's consent. When the user accepts and clicks "yes" nothing happens and the user needs to click the button again for it to take effect while in the backend the user's credits were already counted.

The website's user base are mainly elderly and i can't let this happen since 60% of my users have IE according to google analytics.

This is the call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getNum.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {data: $.toJSON(birthday)},
        success: function(data){

            if (parseInt(data) <= 0){
                $('#waitModal').modal('hide');
                if(parseInt(data) != -10){
                    $('#signInModal').modal('show');
                } else{
                 //no credit
                }

            }else{
                window.location = "generateBirthdayCard.php?num="+parseInt(data)
            }

        }
```

And this is the script (generateBirthdayCard.php) that displays the pdf:

```
if (!$_GET['num']) die("looking for ?url=http://www.....");
$num = trim(escapeshellarg($_GET['num']), "'");

//only if the requested refrence is an integer
if (is_numeric($num)){

   $str = file_get_contents("/tmp/$num.pdf");
   header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
   header('Content-Length: '.strlen($str));
   header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="custom-birthday-cards.pdf"');
   header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
   header('Pragma: public');
   ini_set('zlib.output_compression','0');
   die($str);

}
```

EDIT: This happens in IE8 and also in IE7 when using IE8's developer tool to simulate IE7

Comment: please specify which version(s) of IE you're testing with.

Comment: @Spudley has been updated thanks

Comment: Just allow your users to download the file for 5 minutes. getNum.php might return a hash like `md5($ip . $num);` and also stores this hash with a timestamp in your database. This would also allow to download the pdf again if the first attempt failed

Comment: have you tried location.replace() or document.location.href = ... instead of window.location?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "nothing happens" have you checked the browser cache for a new pdf. I have had issues with IE before where the file is downloaded but IE just wont open it.

Try using fiddler to see if the ajax method did respond with the pdf properly.

Can you open other PDF's in the same browser? e.g. [this one](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/837/cpsid_83708/attachments/Acrobat_Reader_ReleaseNote_9.4.2_8.2.6.pdf)